# Get last non-empty cell in Excel column

Tags: c#, excel

How can we get a number/index of the last empty cell in a column in Excel.

I tried CountA and several others but it returns the count of non-empty cells or suppose there is a cell in the middle of nowhere after actual data with some spaces in that, the UsedRange returns range up to that cell.

What I need is a last non-empty cell in a column where that column may have empty cells in between. Using this last empty cell in that column, I can specify the last row to be considered for use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In VBA you can use something like this on macro code:

```
rcount = Range("A:A").End(xlUp).Row
```

It will return the value of the last non-empty cell on the given column

In C# you can try:

```
Excel.Worksheet sh;
long lastRow;
long fullRow;

sh = app.Workbooks.get_Item("Workbook1.xlsx").Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet1");
fullRow = sh.Rows.Count;
lastRow = sh.Cells[fullRow, 1].get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row; 
//use get_End instead of End
```

Comment: Thanks,
Yes that's true but I need to perform the same in C#

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm. Thanks.
Will test it more for different options later.

Comment: this worked for me. however i needed to change `sh.Cells[fullRow, 1].End` into `get_End` as it is a method